# Unable access uploaded photos using Multer, React, Node.js, Sequelize, PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, sequelize.js, multer

I'm trying to make it so a user to can can click on the default avatar and upload an image of their own. I'm able to successfully upload file to the database, but I can't access it from the client side. I'm not sure if I'm properly storing it. How can I address this?

Client side:

```js
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import Navbar2 from './Navbar2';
    import {
        ProfileContainer,
        ProfileCard,
        Special,
        FileForm,
        FileLabel,
        File,
    } from './styled-components/ProfileStyles';
    import { Avatar } from 'antd';
    import { UserOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
    import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

    import { setProfileInfo } from '../actions/profileInfo-actions';

    export default function Profile() {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const profileInfo = useSelector(
            (state) => state.profileInfo
        );
        const userInfo = useSelector((state) => state.userInfo);

        useEffect(() => {
            setProfileInfo(dispatch);
        }, []);

        const changeProfilePic = async (e) => {
            const file = e.target.files[0];
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', file);
            if (file) {
                if (file.size < 1572864) {
                    if (
                        file.type === 'image/jpeg' ||
                        file.type === 'image/png'
                    ) {
                        const response = await fetch(
                            'http://localhost:4001/user/profile-pic',
                            {
                                method: 'PUT',
                                headers: { token: localStorage.token },
                                body: data,
                            }
                        );
                        if (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            toast.info('Profile Photo Changed');
                        }
                    } else {
                        toast.error('File type must be jpeg or png');
                    }
                } else {
                    toast.error('File size is too large');
                }
            }
        };

        return (
            <>
                <Navbar2 />
                <ProfileContainer>
                    <ProfileCard>
                        <FileForm>
                            <FileLabel htmlFor='pp-upload'>
                                {profileInfo.profileImage == null ? (
                                    <Avatar
                                        size={180}
                                        icon={<UserOutlined />}
                                    />
                                ) : (
                                    <img
                                        src={profileInfo.profileImage}
                                        alt=''
                                    />
                                )}
                            </FileLabel>
                        </FileForm>
                        <File
                            type='file'
                            name='profileImage'
                            id='pp-upload'
                            onChange={changeProfilePic}
                        />
                    </ProfileCard>
                </ProfileContainer>
            </>
        );
    }
```

Server side:

```js
    const router = require('express').Router();
    const { User, Profile } = require('../models');
    const authorization = require('../middleware/authorization');
    const path = require('path');
    const multer = require('multer');

    const upload = multer({ dest: '../public/uploads/' });

    router.put(
        '/profile-pic',
        authorization,
        upload.single('file'),
        async (req, res) => {
            const user = await Profile.findOne({
                where: {
                    userId: req.user,
                },
            });

            const { file } = req;
            const profileImage =
                file.fieldname +
                '-' +
                Date.now() +
                path.extname(file.originalname);
            user.update({ profileImage });
            res.status(200).json({
                status: true,
            });
        }
    );
```

Database Schema:

```js
    'use strict';
    const { Model } = require('sequelize');
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
        class Profile extends Model {
            static associate(models) {
                Profile.belongsTo(models.User, {
                    foreignKey: 'userId',
                    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
                });
            }
        }
        Profile.init(
            {
                bio: DataTypes.STRING,
                profileImage: DataTypes.STRING,
                userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            },
            {
                sequelize,
                modelName: 'Profile',
            }
        );
        return Profile;
    };
```

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to access the image via an Image tag. Have you verified that an uploaded image exists in the database and is actually served properly over http directly?  This should be doable in the browser without using any code and is the simple first step.  Most likely your image is not accessible at the url you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an asp page to write the image in a binary response.

```
<% 

Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Conn.Open("DSN=; User ID=; password=")
sql = "*select image here*"
RS.Open sql, Conn, adOpenForwardOnly

If Not RS.EOF Then
                Response.Expires = 0
                Response.Buffer = TRUE

                Response.Clear
                
                If InStr(RS("REGIMG"),".bmp")>0 Then

                              Response.ContentType = "image/bmp"

               ElseIf InStr(RS("REGIMG"),".jpg")>0 Then

                              Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"

               ElseIf InStr(RS("REGIMG"),".gif")>0 Then

                              Response.ContentType = "image/gif"

               ElseIf InStr(RS("REGIMG"),".tif")>0 Then

                              Response.ContentType = "image/tiff"

               ElseIf InStr(RS("REGIMG"),".png")>0 Then

                              Response.ContentType = "image/png"

               ElseIf InStr(RS("REGIMG"),".svg")>0 Then

                              Response.ContentType = "image/svg+xml"

               End If
                
Response.BinaryWrite RS("REGIMGIMG")
End If
%>
```